# Show button after the text but not outside the cell

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <span class ="name">Can be long, can be short</span>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
</td>

td{
  white-space: no-wrap;
  width:175px;
  position: relative
}
button{
  position:absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

What I get is

[image]

[image]

I want to show name in one line (even if it is outside the cell), but button should be always in cell (on the same line).
If name is short then it should be right after the name, if not then stick to the right of cell.

I used absolute positioning, but in this case button always sticks to the right of the cell. Not what I need for short names.

**So, picture for long name is what I need, but for short name I want yellow button to show near name, not stick to the right side.**

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kchkucv/

Is it possible to do this with CSS?

Comment: Please provide examples (images) of what you want to get in the various situations, or the full code of what you tried, illustrating what doesn't work like you would like.

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: added jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kchkucv/

Answer (score -1):

Andrew what you are asking is not possible with having only one css for both the buttons, either you can have something like this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rohts76/8kchkucv/1

```
.but
{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F2CF66;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D1B358;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
  position:absolute;
  //right: 15px;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.cell{
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:175px;
  position:relative;
}
.cell div{
    margin: 0;
    padding: .35em;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
tr{
    background-color: #8db4e3;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

This code will give you correct thing..

Comment: For long name yellow button is outside the cell.

Comment: @AndrewFount where you want it exactly?

Comment: Yeah what you want is to override the text with button for long text and for short as shown, but that is not possible with single css for button

Comment: I asked whether this possible with css. Answer is no.